# how to change ui componts color according to iOS theme?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am very new to iOS.I want to set the theme for my iOS app & according to theme i am changing the background image.I also want to change the color of other ui component according to background image.I have one way of doing it by saving value in **UserDefaults** & check for every UI Component that would be very lengthy process.Is there any kind of other simple way of doing it in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of appearance proxy. Most of UIKit components have an appearance proxy object. 
Let's take for example a navigation bar.

You can have this code.

```
UIColor *barColor = [UIColor redColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:barColor];
```

Once you execute this, all navigation bars across your app will have a red tint colour. You can customise other things and this way you set your theme globally.

Comment: What about the other components such as text fields & labels etc.

Comment: replace navigation bar with other one in code above

Comment: well if i talk about few screes like on two screens color should be different & other two screens color should be different.How do i achieve that? @Earl Grey